# Oracle Apex - Duplicated VM and now not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, hyper-v, oracle12c

we run an Oracle Server (12C). We want to test the heterogeneous services.

I created a new VM using a backup of the production server, gave it a new mac address and ip address. I updated the mac address in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scritps/ifcfg-eth0`, did a `start_udev` followed by a `service network restart`. That gave me networking.

I gave it a hostname of myServerName-test.local, and also a DNS entry for the same address.

I then changed `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` to have an updated host.

The env variable `ORACLE_SID` is not set to anything, although running a `set ORACLE_SID="RECORDSDB"` does not change it, which I think is an issue for me.

I started `./bin/lsnrctl` and ran a `reload` command, although it's still trying to connect to the production server. What is the way to change this configuration option?

When I try to run `./bin/sqlplus` with the correct username and password, it says - `"ERROR: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified"`.

What is my course of action to resolve this? I've also rebooted it a lot so that won't help anything. Thanks, Harry.

edit: Adding my tnsnames.ora file;

```
RECORDSDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myHostname-test.ap.local)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = recordsdb.local)
    )
)
```

edit 2: Added tnsping output

```
[oracle@ap-ora-records-test dbhome_1]$ ./bin/tnsping 192.168.1.150

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 20-AUG-2014 10:11:54

Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used EZCONNECT adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.150)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

I remember reading about a utility I could use to sort something like this, it was called netmgr, although it required an xserver which i don't have installed. Is this helpful to fixing the issue?

edit 3: lsnrctl status output

```
[oracle@ap-ora-records-test dbhome_1]$ ./bin/lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 21-AUG-2014 11:34:44

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myProductionServer.local)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-01189: The listener could not authenticate the user
```

The `TWO_TASK` was not set, so I set it to be `RECORDSDB` as well, that changed my error when trying to use sqlplus to be `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`.

edit 4:

So I originally changed the hostname on `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` but not `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora` since I didn't realise it existed. This is the output of `lsnrctl reload`

```
[oracle@ap-ora-records-test dbhome_1]$ ./bin/lsnrctl reload

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 21-AUG-2014 11:41:25

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myDevMachine.local)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

So I'm still getting a no listener error but now I'm getting it twice?

When trying to connect to `sqlplus` I get `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener` still.

Edit 5:

I thought that reloading it would start it, I guess not. Does that just reload the configuration then?

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1//bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

```
TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/ap-ora-records-test/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                21-AUG-2014 13:00:24
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/log/diag/tnslsnr/ap-ora-records-test/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ap-ora-records-test.ap.local)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

See below, my TNSNAMES.ora and LISTENER.ora configuration files, I didn't remove the actual hostname however, it's what I've been using all along.

[image: TNSNAMES.ora and LISTENER.ora Configuration files]

Comment: did you check the tnsping http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG378

Comment: Updated the original post!

Comment: Your tnsping should be against the alias, RECORDSDB, not the IP address. Are `myHostname-test.ap.local` and 192.168.1.150 the same thing, and does your VM have multiple IP addresses? What address/port is the listener on, if it's up at all? What does `lsnrctl status` show? Are you specifying that TNS alias as part of your SQL*Plus command, or is it defined in TWO_TASK?

Comment: I did also try using the hostname as well, it gave the same results. They are the same thing. The VM does not have multiple IP addresses, I can not say what the status shows until tomorrow as I don't have the VPN on this computer and I'm at home now. I was not specifying the TNS as part of the sqlplus command, I do not know if it is in TWO_TASK, could you tell me how to check that please? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Updated the original post with more details.

Comment: So... your listener isn't running? Looks like you haven't updated the listener.ora and it's still trying to bind to the prod servers IP address, not your VM's IP address?

Comment: Updated again, I had to set up a new backup HDD but see the latest edit, that has been resolved but created new issues.

Comment: You can't reload the listener if it isn't running. Did you do `lsnrctl start` after changing the address in the `listener.ora`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't changed the listening IP address in your `listener.ora`. After you have done that you'll need to start the listener with `lsnrctl start`. You can then verify that is has started with `lsnrctl status`.

Once the listener is up it may take a while for the database to register itself. You can force that with `alter system register`. If it won't register then check if you have the `local_listener` database parameter set, and if so if it's to the production address/port. If it is then you'll need up change that too, with `alter system`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I am finally connected now. I didn't realise that I would have to wait for the DB to register itself. Ignore my last edit! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and problem was that defined IP in hosts file was faulty. 
Check if in listener.ora defined hostname is reachable.